# Using an inherit method to extend its functionality

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to extend a method doing the following:

`

```
class Parent:
    def extract(self):
        #code

class Child(Parent):
    def extract(self):
        self.extract()
        self.parse()
    
    def parse(self):
        #code
```

`
I do not know if this is the right way to do it but my kernel explodes when I try to do this with my code. What I want to achieve is to use the code from the parent class + new code from the child class knowing that the parent class will be inherited by other classes that would not need to have the extract method extended.

Comment: *"but my kernel explodes"* is a funny but absolutely nonsense error description. You have an infinite recursion because `self.extract()` is not a good idea,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access the base class one of function, but you already override into the child class. You can do it using with this way;

```
class Parent:
    def extract(self):
        print("base class extract")


class Child(Parent):
    def extract(self):
        super(Child, self).extract()
        self.parse()

    def parse(self):
        print("child class parse")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_field = Child()
    sample_field.extract()

# output:
# base class extract
# child class parse
```

Comment: Why are you using Child and self inside super? would it work with only super()?

Comment: yes it works. My reason for using it is habit. The reason for this habit is that a class is derived from more than one parent class in the normal world. Ability to select which parent class's function when there is more than one base class. Think of it like this, parent->child->grandchild . If you call a function in the "Grandchild" class without writing anything inside the super() function, it will call it from the "child" class. But if you call it by saying super(parent, self) this time you can access the functions of the parent class in a lower layer.